# Using jQuery AJAX to communicate with server, can I set a cookie/session?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my example, I am sending login details to a server-side script via AJAX that in turn sets a session/cookie variable.

My question is will the cookie/session be set after I get a response, or do I actually have to visit the server-side script the regular way to set them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your cookie/session will be set. You can try it by send another request.